# webassembly compilation error using emsdk

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

trying to compile my cpp code using emscripten in VSCode but [throws an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3iH9.png) saying conio.h file not found. Is there any way to include conio.h or a substitute, below is what the terminal says

> PS C:\Users\abc\emsdk> em++ f:/fighter/source.cpp -s WASM=1 -o f:/fighter/source.html
> f:/fighter/source.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'conio.h' file not found
> #include "conio.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> em++: error: 'C:/Users/abc/emsdk/upstream/bin\clang++.exe -target wasm32-unknown-emscripten -fignore-exceptions -fvisibility=default -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr -DEMSCRIPTEN -D__EMSCRIPTEN_major__=3 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_minor__=1 -D__EMSCRIPTEN_tiny__=18 -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -IC:\Users\abc\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot\include\SDL --sysroot=C:\Users\abc\emsdk\upstream\emscripten\cache\sysroot -Xclang -iwithsysroot/include\compat f:/fighter/source.cpp -c -o C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\emscripten_temp_px_3ahn7\source_0.o' failed (returned 1)

here is the code if anyone wants to look into it

```
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "ctime"
#include "emscripten.h"
using namespace std;
bool GameOver = false;


// function to undertake all the game proecessing

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
void Processing() {
    int choose;
    char ch;
    system("color 04");
    cout << "WELCOME" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Character " << i << endl;
    }
    cout << "choose character number: ";
    cin >> choose;


    if (choose > 4) {
        cout << "Enter valid character number: ";
        cin >> choose;

    }
    cout << "Selected Character is " << choose << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    system("color 02");
    cout << "ENEMY IS CHARACTER " << random << endl;

int hp1 = 100;
int hp2 = 100;

cout << "Character " << choose << "(health " << hp1 << ")" << " VS. Character " << random << "(health " << hp2 << ")" << endl << endl;


while (!GameOver)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int rand1 = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    int rand2 = (rand() % 100) + 1;

    int NewHp1 = hp1 - rand1;
    int NewHp2 = hp2 - rand2;


    cout << "Press any key to attack" << endl << endl;
    if (NewHp2 <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Enemy has 0 hp left"<<endl<<"YOU WIN!!" << endl;
        GameOver = true;
    }

    else if (NewHp1 <= 0)
    {
        system("color 04");
        cout << "You have 0 hp left"<<endl<<"YOU LOSE" << endl;
        GameOver = true;
    }
    else{
    hp1 = NewHp1;
    hp2 = NewHp2;
     cout << "Enemy has " << NewHp2 << " health left." << endl << endl;

        system("pause");

        cout << "You have " << NewHp1 << " health left." << endl << endl;
    } 
}
```

}

// main function to display output as long as GameOver is false

int main() {
while (!GameOver)
Processing();
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rabbid76 my bad, ive made the required changes to the post

Comment: What happens when you use angle brackets instead of quotes for your `#include` statements? `#include <iostream>` etc.

Comment: @TonyK Throws the same error with angular brackets too